# CHAP Password decrypt - Freeradius

Tags: php, encryption, radius, freeradius

I'm using Freeradius to authenticate user from my server using php code

```
update control {
    Reply-Message := `/usr/bin/php -f /etc/raddb/auth.php '%{User-Name}' '%{CHAP-Password}' '%{CHAP-Challenge}' auth`
}
```

it return `CHAP-Password = 0xa2a421bf267fbffabe5696cf1c6d54f479`

and the CHAP-password is Hashing, but i don't have clear text password in database, the password is hashed .

It is working fine with PAP Protocol, but i need to use CHAP for other server configuration

So my question: is there anyway to decrypt the CHAP-Password , or if this is not possible to tell CHAP not to hashing the password in configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for many and many hours I finally make chap authenticate with my database:

**First:** I'm working on freeradius 3, because there are many changes form radius 2 and radius 3

**Second: Database Configuration**

I'm using mysql with 2 Databases like this:

1. members

   - users

     - id
     - username
     - password
     - .......
     - .......
   - ........
2. radius

   - radcheck

     - id
     - username
     - attribute
     - op
     - value
   - radpostauth
   - ......

You need to configure sql file in this root

```
sudo nano mods-available/sql
```

And change this values

```
driver = "rlm_sql_mysql"
dialect = "mysql"
server = "localhost"
login = "your_database_username"
password = "your_database_password"
```

Then save and restart the radius by:

```
sudo service radiusd restart
```

If radius restart without error, so the configuration is correct

After restarting radius you need to copy this file to *mods-enabled*

so radius run this configuration, because all files in *mods-enabled* is what radius running it

```
sudo cp mods-available/sql mods-enabled/sql
```

To check if everything running OK

```
sudo radiusd -XC
```

This command run debug on radius, and return errors .

if the end of this debug is

> Configuration appears to be OK

so everything is fine until now

**Third: Database Connection and Authenticate**

Now we need to authenticate the username via *CHAP* , so we need to write query to select the username from *user* table

This query will be in this file *queries.conf* in this root

```
sudo nano mods-config/sql/main/mysql/queries.conf
```

And change the `authorize_check_query` to

```
authorize_check_query = "\
    SELECT members.user.id as id, \
    members.user.username as username, \
    'Cleartext-Password' as attribute, \
    members.user.password as value, \
    ':=' as op \
FROM members.user \
WHERE members.user.username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' \
ORDER BY members.user.id"
```

FYI , the password must be in plain text, because as you see the attribute is *Cleartext-Password*

Now let's add in table *user* row with username = "ahmed" and password = "test"

and try to test authentication

```
radtest -t chap ahmed test localhost 1812 testing123
```

if you receive

> Received Access-Accept Id 105 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:38259 length 20

So you are Done,

also i want to thanks  @MatthewNewton for his answer and comments on my question :D

Comment: I followed you got accepted message response but attribute reply empty I don't know what config I am missed

Answer (score 1):

CHAP is challenge-response. The hex you see is not an encrypted password and there is no way to "decrypt" it to get a plain-text password.

With PAP you can have an encrypted password on the server, or plaintext. You are sent a plaintext password which you can test.

With CHAP you need the plaintext password on the server to check that the response to the challenge is correct.

So you can't do what you want to do in the current form.

Comment: Thanks you for answer ,
I if i have plain text password let's say "123456" and when using CHAP it sends `'%{CHAP-Password}' '%{CHAP-Challenge}'  `
How to check if response to the challenge is correct ?

Comment: You should set Cleartext-Password to "123456" in FreeRADIUS. Then for chap auth the Access-Request that comes in will contain a CHAP-Password attribute. The `chap` module will then use the Cleartext-Password to verify that the CHAP-Password attribute is correct. There is no need to use php to process CHAP attributes, that is what the chap module is there for.

Comment: but i have database with user name and cleartext-password, so i have to save all this recordes in users file to make FreeRADIUS authenticate ? right?

Comment: No, just configure FreeRADIUS to read your database. The users file is only one of many ways to get data into FreeRADIUS. See for example the "sql" module (you can change all the queries, so don't have to stick to the database schema in the default configuration).

Comment: OK, this what i'm looking for right now, is how to configure FreeRADIUS to read from database, cause the sql file have configuration for table radius, also i use mysql, could you give my an example

Comment: i have database **"radius"** and database **"members"** in same mysql inside database **"members"** i have table "_users_" with columns "_username_, _password_, ...." and as you tell me i need to read data from database, and i think i need to write query inside **queries.conf** to authenticate , but i don't know where to write that query, could you please help me
@MatthewNewton

Comment: Your easiest way is probably to use unlang and an SQL xlat to pull the password from the database into the Cleartext-Password attribute. See http://wiki.freeradius.org/modules/Rlm_sql#sql-xlat. The freeradius-users mailing list is probably more appropriate for this discussion.